# Is this proof that sigma is a fieldautomorphism legit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I read a proof of the following theorem in "Basic abstract algebra" by Bhattacharya, Jain and Nagpaul and I thought that the proof looked overcomplicated. I have written my own proof of the theorem and would like to know if there are any mistakes, or if the proof seems legit.

**Theorem:**

Let $E$ be an algebraic extension of a field F, and let $\sigma : E \rightarrow E$ be a 1-1 homomorphism of $E$ into itself over $F$. Then $\sigma$ is onto and, hence, an automorphism of $E$.

**Proof:**

Let $a \in E$ and let $p(x)$ be its minimal polynomial over $F$. Now, $\sigma$ must map a root of $p(x)$ onto a root of $p(x)$. Let $\{a_i\}$ be the set of distinct roots of $p(x)$ that lie in $E$. Then since $\sigma$ is 1-1 the set $\{\sigma(a_i)\}$ of roots of $p(x)$ that lie in E must have the same size as $\{a_i\}$ and therefore $\{\sigma(a_i)\} = \{a_i\}$. This means that since $a \in \{a_i\}$ then $a \in \{\sigma(a_i)\} $. And therefore $ a \in \sigma(E)$ for all $a \in E$,and so $\sigma$ is onto.

Is this good enough? Are there any mistakes?

Comment: Does "$\sigma$ is a homomorphism over $F$" imply that $F$ is fixed pointwise by $\sigma$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I do not understand your question. What do you mean by "fixed pointwise" ?

Comment: It means that $\sigma(t)=t$ for all $t\in F$. (You seem to be using this in your argument.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Yes, I assume that is what is meant.

Comment: In that case, your proof is fine. What does the argument in the book you cite do beyond this?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo It creates the subfield $E^{\prime}$ containing $F$ and is generated by all the roots of $p(x)$ that lie in $E$. Thus $E^{\prime}$ is finite algebraic extension of $F$. Then states that  $\sigma$ must map a root of $p(x)$ onto a root of $p(x)$, and hence map $E^{\prime}$ into itself. Now $\sigma(E^{\prime}) \cong E$ because $\sigma$ is $1-1$. Thus $[\sigma(E^{\prime}):F] = [E^{\prime} : F]$. But since $\sigma(E^{\prime})$ is a subspace $E^{\prime}$, it follows that $\sigma(E^{\prime}) = E^{\prime}$. This implies that there is $b \in E^{\prime}$ such that $\sigma(b) = a$

Comment: @Improve: A homomorphism from a field is always $1-1$ (unless you admit zero as a homomorphism), so that assumption is sort of redundant.

Comment: @tomasz Well, yes, initially I wrote embedding, but then changed it since I was not sure whether people would know what I meant, so I just wrote the book's definiton of an embedding instead, which is a 1-1 homomorphism.

Comment: If it is said "homomorphism of $\;E\;$ **over** $\;F\;$ it may well mean it is talking of a homomorphism of the *vector space* $\;E\;$ over $\;F\;$ , and thus Tomasz's comment wouldn't apply here. Otherwise that comment's accurate and we need no other data.